# Handling long links in doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen, long-parameter-list

Given a function declaration with a long parameter list such as:

```
uint8 rtSetTime(RTIME *rtime, uint8 day, uint8 month, uint16 year,
    uint8 hour, uint8 minute, uint8 second);
```

is there a way to split the parameter list across multiple lines such that doxygen will still parse the `@link` command correctly? At present I can only get it to work if the function declaration is on a single line, ie:

```
@link rtSetTime(RTIME *rtime, uint8 day, uint8 month, uint16 year, uint8 hour, uint8 minute, uint8 second) rtSetTime @endlink
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use the parameter names in the link.
Assuming rtSetTime is not an overloaded function it is not really needed to specify all parameter types either.

Here are a number of ways to link to the function, from shortest to longest. The last two also work in case the function is overloaded.

```
/** @mainpage 
 *  - #rtSetTime 
 *  - @ref rtSetTime "rtSetTime"
 *  - @ref rtSetTime() "rtSetTime"
 *  - @link rtSetTime rtSetTime@endlink 
 *  - @link rtSetTime() rtSetTime@endlink
 *  - @ref rtSetTime(RTIME*,uint8,uint8,uint16,uint8,uint8,uint8) "rtSetTime"
 *  - @link rtSetTime(RTIME*,uint8,uint8,uint16,uint8,uint8,uint8) rtSetTime @endlink
 */
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for taking the time to describe how to use the `@link` command properly.